# How to display size in kilo bytes of webpage?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I am developing mobile application in browser and I desperately need to know the total webpage size.

Is there a extension in chrome or firefox that tell you how much KB has the webpage consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools online that can do that for you, as examples : http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ or http://gtmetrix.com/

You can find a lot more by searching `website speed` with google.

Comment: Thankyou ... I was searching webpage size test and all I was getting was the display size of webpage.

Comment: The google page speed does give suggestions for optimizing the site..But why cant they give simple data such as total KB loaded? Can you tell me some chrome extensions that you may know....this is so simple...yet there is no extension for it.

Comment: @HS Well, for example, if you look at http://tools.pingdom.com/ the first data they give you about the page you ask is `number of requests`, `load time` and `total size of the page`. Isn't what you where looking for ? But sorry, I don't know extensions doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The *Web Developer Toolbar* on my (desktop) Firefox has the information under "Information"->"Show document size" (or similar, sorry, had to translate that back to English). It shows the sizes of the HTML document itself, every loaded component (CSS files, scripts, images), and total size. All of them in transferred and uncompressed sizes.

ps: If testing this from a desktop PC, one should bear in mind that a web framework used for the site might offer another representation to a mobile browser than to a desktop browser.